# hide specific row with value 1

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I want to hide all the rows has value 1 in field "Fault" in the table
I tried

`=IIF( Fields!Fault.Value = 1 , True, False)`

but it's not hide , I guess because I have few row groups 
[Report picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjnbw.png)

Comment: do you want to hide just the detail rows or the whole group if every detail row has fault=1.
BTW, you don't need the `IIF`, for your details row you can just use `=Fields!Fault.Value=1` as this will return true/false anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the whole row right click on the detail **Row Visibility > Visibility > Show or hide based on an expression** and write in the following code:

```
=IIF(Fields!Fault.Value = 1, True, False)
```

If the Value is `1` then the whole row now will be hidden. You can add this in a group detail row or just in the detail row.